# Hide Plugin Custom Post Type Menu Link

Tags: plugins, functions, themes

I installed a plugin that has a custom post type, that looks like the picture below:

[image]

WhatI's like to do is hide the "Pictures" link in this menu. It's a custom post type. The link looks like: `edit.php?post_type=cbs_pictures`

I tried:

```
function plt_hide_custom_post_type_ui_menus() {
    remove_submenu_page('menu-posts-cbs_booking', 'edit.php?post_type=cbs_pictures');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'plt_hide_custom_post_type_ui_menus', 11);
```

I also tried:

```
function your_custom__remove_menu_items() {
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=cbs_pictures' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'your_custom_remove_menu_items' );
```

but neither of these snippets worked...the "Pictures" link still shows.

Anyone know how this could be hidden? I would like to still be able to use the url to access the page, I would just like the "Pictures" menu item to be hidden. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those methods that you were using, remove the page totally. If you were the plugin author I would suggest to create the admin page calling `add_submenu_page` with a parent id of `null`. Since you can't change the plugin code the only way to achieve this is using `CSS`.

Read [this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18850) ticket for more information about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, I put this in my functions file, which successfully hid my menu item :-) Thanks @Had1z for the suggestion!

```
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_style');

function custom_style() {
    echo '<style>
        #menu-posts-cbs_booking .wp-submenu li:nth-child(6) {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>';
}
```

Hope this helps someone, marking @Had1z's answer as the correct one since it steered me in the right direction :-)

Thanks,
Josh